Can the 'Share' popup in Discussions use a short link?
Currently, if I click Share (next to Follow and Flag) on the Discussions Sandbox, I get https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79238102/discussions-sandbox. This isn't consistent with SO, which omits the title (SO also includes the user ID when signed in).
This isn't wrong, in that it works, but I'd rather it use a short link for consistency and to be more convenient if I'm copying somewhere and a shorter link would be handy. All of these work fine, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79238102
https://stackoverflow.com/q/79238102
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79238102

I'd probably suggest the first or second option, though.

I'm curious, what effect would this change have? Is it just for a consistency, or is there some other benefit to doing this?

Oh...!?, never knew you could click on the 'Share' Link to get some fancy Popup indeed, ah-ah...! I always do/did 'Right-Click' + 'Copy  Link'. (FF25-133, Win10). (And then edit the Link if I know it can be shortened... (especially in Comments, due to the 600-Char-Limit).) // So the 'Share' Link has never been "a Popup" for me...

@cigien Not sure it's worth it, but both. It would be consistent with SO Q&A, but a shorter link is also sometimes handy to save the end-user from having to strip off the unnecessary part of the URL if they're space-constrained.

I, once again, would rather they fix Discussions before they start adding "nice to haves". If they followed MoSCoW principles, I'd say this fits in the Could have category, while there's are many outstanding Must haves.

Even without the label it isn't consistent with Q&A, Q&A doesn't have a /beta in the url. And if it does not go to the trash heap, neither will discussions at some point... I think it is a little too early to be worrying about the share popup. Whatever url's are produced and pasted now already do not stand the test of time.

I wonder if you can get an Announcer badge for a discussions post….

@JeremyBanks yes. I have at least two from that avenue.
